# Saltar entre inputs con una clase en especifico

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo el siguiente código para saltar entre `inputs` que tengan `clase` monto con la tecla `enter`, esta función se la asigno a los `inputs` cuando los creo a nivel de `javascript`. Ni el `focus` ni el `select` me están funcionando. Uso el `.next` para ubicarme en el siguiente `inp` con clase monto guardándolo en la variable `a`. Al hacer `console.log` de `a` no me muestra solo el siguiente sino todos los `inputs` con con clase `monto`.

```
$(monto_inp).on('keydown', function () {

    $(".monto").keypress(function (e) {
        //console.log(e);
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var a = $( ".monto" ).next( ".monto" );
            console.log(a);
            a.focus();
            a.select();

        }
    });
});
```

EDIT1: Lo creo de esta forma, esto creacion de input se acciona cuando alguien toca un boton, asi que son n cantidad de monto_inp

```
// Creacion de input para "monto"
var monto_inp = document.createElement("input");
monto_inp.name = "monto";
monto_inp.placeholder = "Monto";
monto_inp.classList.add('detalle_pago');
monto_inp.classList.add('monto');
```

Esto es lo que muestra el console.log

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes agregar un poco de código para saber de donde sacas por ejemplo **monto_inp** y un poco de **html**

Comment: pero tienes una función? estoy un poco confundido

Comment: la propiedad que mas se asemeja a lo que buscas es .nextElementSibling que buscara al siguiente elemento hermano, una vez lo tengas podrias usar una condicional para darle el foco si su clase es Monto, de lo contrario buscar el siguiente elemento. Siento no poder enviar el codigo hoy estoy desde el cell.